# Optimise nested for loop and if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops, object

I have an if statement inside two nested for loops in my javascript code as below.

The problem is that the execution slows down when I have to compare thousands of objects in the array as the loop iterates through the entire array just to check for a single matching value.

When the key in data object matches with the id of an object from the `arr` array it adds a username key to the objects in `arr` array.

Please run the following code and see the output :

```js
var data = { 1: 'John',
  2: 'Josehp',
  8: 'Marley',
  3: 'George',
  4: 'Stella',
  5: 'Stanley',
  123: 'Juhi'
}



var arr = [ { id: '1'
   },
  { id: '2'
  },
  { id: '10'
    },
  { id: '3'
    },
  { id: '4'
    },
  { id: '13'
    },
  { id: '5'
    }
];

var x;
for (x in data) {
 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if (arr[i].id == x) {
 arr[i].username = data[x];
 }
     }
  }
console.log(arr)
```

How can I optimise this code to avoid nested loops or simply improve the performance ?

Comment: `if loop`? Do you mean if statement?

Comment: corrected it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be something like this will help?

```
arr.forEach((user) => {
    if (data[user.id] !== undefined) {
        user.username = data[user.id]
    }
});
```

Comment: really loved this short answer

Answer (score 1):

You could take a single loop and check if the object exists and update the array.

```js
var data = { 1: 'John', 2: 'Josehp', 8: 'Marley', 3: 'George', 4: 'Stella', 5: 'Stanley', 123: 'Juhi' },
    array = [ { id: '1' }, { id: '2' }, { id: '10' }, { id: '3' }, { id: '4' }, { id: '13' }, { id: '5' }],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].id in data) {
        array[i].username = data[array[i].id];
    }
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop through the `arr` array and set each item's username based on the property of `data` with the same key.

```js
var data = {
  1: 'John',
  2: 'Josehp',
  8: 'Marley',
  3: 'George',
  4: 'Stella',
  5: 'Stanley',
  123: 'Juhi'
};

var arr = [{ id: '1' },
{ id: '2' },
{ id: '10' },
{ id: '3' },
{ id: '4' },
{ id: '13' },
{ id: '5' }];


arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.username = data[item.id];
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

`data` is an hash with `id` as key, so access it's elements by id is an `O(1)` operation.

This means that you can have a single loop through your `arr` variable making your algorithm linear (`O(n)`):

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )
  if ( data[arr[i].id] )
    arr[i].username = data[arr[i].id]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
var data = { 1: 'John',
  2: 'Josehp',
  8: 'Marley',
  3: 'George',
  4: 'Stella',
  5: 'Stanley',
  123: 'Juhi'
}



var arr = [ { id: '1'
   },
  { id: '2'
  },
  { id: '10'
    },
  { id: '3'
    },
  { id: '4'
    },
  { id: '13'
    },
  { id: '5'
    }
];

let out = arr.map(({id}) => (data[id]? {id, username: data[id]}: {id}));
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `map` with a ternary operator and spreading:

```js
var data = { 1: 'John', 2: 'Josehp', 8: 'Marley', 3: 'George', 4: 'Stella', 5: 'Stanley', 123: 'Juhi'}

var arr = [{id: '1'},{id: '2'},{id: '10'},{id: '3'},{id: '4'},{id: '13'},{id: '5'}];

arr = arr.map(e => data[e.id] ? { ...e, username: data[e.id] } : e);

console.log(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = { 1: 'John', 2: 'Josehp', 8: 'Marley', 3: 'George', 4: 'Stella', 5: 'Stanley', 123: 'Juhi' },
array = [ { id: '1' }, { id: '2' }, { id: '10' }, { id: '3' }, { id: '4' }, { id: '13' }, { id: '5' }],
i;

for (var m in array){
 array[m].username = data[array[m].id]
}

console.log(array);
```